# Adobe AEM Workflows - Is It Possible to Modify Payload via EMCAScript

Tags: javascript, aem-6, adobe-exprience-manager

I am working on creating an AEM Workflow. One of the steps in this workflow is a Process that calls an EMCAScript file which renames the Asset if it has spaces:

```
var workflowData = workItem.getWorkflowData();
var pType = workflowData.getPayloadType();
if (workflowData.getPayloadType() == "JCR_PATH") {
    var path = workflowData.getPayload().toString();
    var parentPath = path.replace('/jcr:content/renditions/original', '');
    if (workflowSession.getSession().itemExists(parentPath)) { 
        var replaceChars = new RegExp(" ", "g");

        var node = workflowSession.getSession().getItem(parentPath);
        var name = node.getPath();
        var newName = name.replace(replaceChars, "_");
        log.warn('Name : ' + name + ". New Name: " + newName);
        if(name != newName) {
        log.warn(newName);
         workflowSession.getSession().move(name, newName);
        node.save();
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("Item does not exist: " + path);
    }
}
```

The logic works as expected - the file is renamed. Other steps in the workflow seem to complete correctly as well; i.e. the thumbnail seems to be properly extracted.

However, the asset itself is "stuck" in the processing state. When I look at the failure details for the job, I see the following:

```
com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: Process execution resulted in an error
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:201)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.JobHandler.process(JobHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.JobConsumerManager$JobConsumerWrapper.process(JobConsumerManager.java:502)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.startJob(JobQueueImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl.access$100(JobQueueImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.JobQueueImpl$1.run(JobQueueImpl.java:229)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException: Failed to execute process
    at com.day.cq.workflow.compatibility.CQWorkflowProcessRunner.execute(CQWorkflowProcessRunner.java:108)
    at com.adobe.granite.workflow.core.job.HandlerBase.executeProcess(HandlerBase.java:191)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowException: execute: cannot process video, asset [{/content/dam/this file name has spaces.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/original}] in payload doesn't exist for workflow [{VolatileWorkItem_node2_var_workflow_instances_server0_2023-02-17_update_asset_58}].
    at com.day.cq.dam.video.AbstractFFMpegProcess.execute(AbstractFFMpegProcess.java:75)
    at com.day.cq.workflow.compatibility.CQWorkflowProcessRunner.execute(CQWorkflowProcessRunner.java:93)
    ... 9 more
```

I understand the error: the Workflow cannot find the original file since it has been moved/renamed. However, what I don't understand is why I am receiving that error from the "FFmpeg thumbnails" step when it is *before* the step (Process near the bottom) that does the renaming.

Is it possible to update the payload (Jcr Path) so that all steps in the Workflow see the updated name? I am using Adobe AEM 6.5.10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a "hacky" way of changing a payload path of a running workflow.

I prefaced with "hacky" way because it is not documented and would require you to have an extra task step in your workflow.

The gist of it is:

1. Save the value of the new file name of your payload somewhere
2. After the step wherein the payload was renamed, create a Task step.
3. In the task "Pre create task script" have a script that essentially gets the value of the new file name, and set it to the content path of the task:

```
task.setContentPath(newFileName);
```

4. Task needs to be completed and after the task is completed, your payload would have adjusted to the new location.